# Convert GMT to IST in java?

Tags: java

I have a GMT field in which the user enter a time to be converted to IST (for eg: in hour field 18, minute field 30, in session field am/pm). I need to get those inputs and convert to IST in java???

Comment: IST = Indian/Irish/Israel/Iran Standard Time?

Comment: @harishtps You missed the point of the comment by Kutik. The 3-4 letter abbreviations are *not* actual time zones, are not standardized, and are not even unique! Your `IST` is used in at least four different places on earth. Avoid these pseudo-zones. A [real time zone is named](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in a `continent/region` format such as `Asia/Kolkata`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is very easy and obvious if you realize that the timezone is only relevant for a date formatted as String - second/millisecond timestamps (of which `java.util.Date` is merely a wrapper) are always implicitly UTC (what GMT is properly called). And converting between such a timestamp and a string always uses a timezone, both ways.

So this is what you need to do:

```
    DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(patternString);
    utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    DateFormat indianFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(patternString);
    indianFormat .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
    Date timestamp = utcFormat.parse(inputString);
    String output = indianFormat.format(timestamp);
```

Comment: GMT and UTC have slightly different definitions, but the overall effect is *de minimis* in practice.

Comment: Should not it be `indianFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));`?

Answer (score 3):

Well, joda-time *is* easier. Try something like this

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(<year>,<month>,<day>, <hour>,<minute>, <second>, <millisecond>);
DateTime dtIST = dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST");
```

Note here that the use of the three letter abbreviation is deprecated and that time zones should be referred to like "America/Los_Angeles" refers to PST.I haven't the time to get the corrsesponding for IST right now but something should be left as an exercise to the reader!

UPDATE: As Basil Bourque states in the comments, Joda-Time is in maintenance mode. Use java.time instead.

Comment: The reason that the three-letter form is deprecated is that it is ambiguous (e.g., I know for sure that BST stands for both British Summer Time – i.e., GMT+DST – and for Brazilian Standard Time). The “continent/city” form has none of those problems.

Comment: Update: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), and advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.of( 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) , 
    LocalTime.of( 18 , 30 ), 
    ZoneOffset.UTC 
).atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) )
```

## Details

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

Get the current date in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) as a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) without time-of-day and without time zone or offset.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Specify the time per user inputs as a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) without a date and without a time zone or offset.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of( 18 , 30 );
```

Put them together with an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero, [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) itself as the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC), to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( localDate , localTime, ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Apply a time zone as a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` for India time. Or by IST did you mean Irish Standard Time? Iran Standard Time?

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z );
```

See this [code live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/bK3DR6).

> localDate.toString(): 2017-02-13
>
> localTime.toString(): 18:30
>
> odt.toString(): 2017-02-13T18:30Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2017-02-14T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

When I add the below code, it worked for me.

```
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");
                            utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                            DateFormat indianFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-HH-mm");
                            utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
                            Date timestamp = utcFormat.parse("2019-04-26-19-00");
                            String istTime = indianFormat.format(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'r looking for **Indian TimeZone** do this

> "GMT+5:30"

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
sdf.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30")
```